# getting id from button to a isset post in php

Tags: php, android

In my app I have some buttons, when I click, it saves data to a mysql database, and it works.
The problem is, that I have 10-15 pages, where I need to save some data, so instead of having 10-15 php page, that save the data in mysql, I want to use one.

this is what worked

My button

```
    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and my php

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
//initial query
$query = "INSERT INTO comments ( username, title, message ) VALUES ( :user, :title, :message ) ";

//Update query
$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
    ':title' => $_POST['title'],
    ':message' => $_POST['message']
);
```

my java

```
package overskov.rhkbrand;




@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class AddComment extends Fragment {  

private EditText lys, skilt, door, etDate;
private Button  mSubmit;

  // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script

//localhost :  
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String POST_COMMENT_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/addcomment.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String POST_COMMENT_URL = "http://overskov-hansen.dk/addcomment.php";

//testing from a real server:
//private static final String POST_COMMENT_URL = "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/addcomment.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";






public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.opgang_a, container, false);              
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.add_comment);
    lys =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lys);        
    skilt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.skilt);
    door = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.door);
    etDate = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDate);



    //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");  
    try {  
         etDate.setText(format.format(new Date()));


} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    mSubmit = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.under_a);
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            PostComment mTask = new PostComment(getActivity());
            mTask.execute();                
            //new PostComment().execute();
        }
    });     
    return rootView;
}

//////////////////////



class PostComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private Context context;
  ProgressDialog prog;

  public PostComment(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Posting Comment...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String post_lys = lys.getText().toString();
        String post_skilt = skilt.getText().toString();
        String post_door = door.getText().toString();
       String post_etDate = etDate.getText().toString();

        //We need to change this:
        String post_username = "admin";

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lys", post_lys));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("skilt", post_skilt));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("door", post_door));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("etDate", post_etDate));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json;                
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);



            // full json response
            Log.d("Post Comment attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Comment Added!", json.toString());    
                //finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Comment Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }


}
```

}

my php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");


if (isset($_POST['under_a'])) {
//initial query
$query = "INSERT INTO under_a ( username, lys, skilt, door, etDate ) VALUES ( :user, :lys, :skilt, :door, :etDate ) ";


 //Update query
 $query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username'],
    ':lys' => $_POST['lys'],
    ':skilt' => $_POST['skilt'],
    ':door' => $_POST['door'],
     ':etDate' => $_POST['etDate']


 );


//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

    //or just use this use this one:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error. Couldn't add post!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Successfully Added!";
echo json_encode($response);

}


?>
```

and my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:background="#000000"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:text="@string/opgang_a"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/etDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:cursorVisible="false"
      android:ems="15"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
      android:inputType="date"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textStyle="bold" />
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/lys" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lys"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:inputType="text"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:text="@string/skilte"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/skilt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:inputType="text" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView4"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="20dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:text="@string/door"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/door"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    android:textSize="14sp" >

      <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/under_a"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="@string/gem_data"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

my logcat

```
02-20 20:51:09.317: E/JSON Parser(19779): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of
```

02-20 20:51:09.322: W/dalvikvm(19779): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ad2700)
02-20 20:51:09.332: E/AndroidRuntime(19779): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 20:51:09.332: E/AndroidRuntime(19779): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 20:51:09.332: E/AndroidRuntime(19779):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-20 20:51:09.332: E/AndroidRuntime(19779):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)

Comment: Please show more code so we can see where the variables come from. Also, $_POST['name of item'] not id of item.

Comment: dont mind the post name has change

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make sure your button have name parameter like

```
<input type="button" id="under_b" name="under_b"/>
```

otherwise it won't be passed to POST.

Comment: ya in php, and that works, but in my app, my button?

Comment: In your xml at the button tag is it possible to use somethink like android:name to set name property?

Comment: just tryed android:name="under_a" but still the same